# How to add percentage label without changing order by Google Chat

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to add percentage marks to number labels and found a option for it.

```
{hAxis: {format: 'percent'}}
```

But it also multiple the number by `100`.

> > For instance, {hAxis: { format:'#,###%'} } displays the values "1,000%", "750%", and "50%" for values 10, 7.5, and 0.5.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats

How can I just add `%` to the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try adding custom axis labels, or `ticks`...

using object notation, you can provide both a...

value (`v:`) and a formatted value (`f:`)

then using google's `NumberFormat` class, build each `tick` manually...

```
var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  suffix: '%'
});
```

...

```
ticks.push({
  v: data.getValue(i, 0),
  f: formatPercent.formatValue(data.getValue(i, 0))
});
```

...

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: ticks
}
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y'],
    [1, 1],
    [10, 2],
    [20, 3],
    [30, 4]
  ]);

  var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0',
    suffix: '%'
  });

  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    ticks.push({
      v: data.getValue(i, 0),
      f: formatPercent.formatValue(data.getValue(i, 0))
    });
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      ticks: ticks
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```